# OpenWeatherMap json value meaning

Tags: json, weather, weather-api, openweathermap

I working with windows phone 8 apps using Json from OpenWeatherMap API and I can't find any documentation about each value that appear in Json, maybe anyone can tell me what that mean? so I can give much better user experience instead of using only numbers

```
[{"dt":1388808000,"temp":{"day":301.98,"min":298.06,"max":301.98,"night":298.06,"eve":300.7,"morn":301.98},
"pressure":1018.57,"humidity":87,
"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],
"speed":2.71,"deg":273,"clouds":48,"rain":4}
```

so value that I don't know what it mean are

```
speed = 2.71
deg = 273
clouds = 48
rain = 4
```

what is these number mean?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

the meaning of this values is:

**-Speed** : wind speed in mps.

**-deg** : wind direction in degrees.

**-clouds** : cloudiness in %.

**-rain** : precipitation volume in mm.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this API description at http://openweathermap.org/forecast16#JSON.

Parameters are described under JSON example.